# Test fails after migration from mockito-core:2.23.4 to mockito-core:3.4.6

Tags: mockito, spring-test

I migrated to mockito-core:3.4.6. After that, some of my methods does not succeed anymore.

```
 ...
 @SpyBean
 MyInstance myInstance;
 ...


 doAnswer(params -> params.getArgument(0)).when(myInstance).myMethod(any());
```

I get this error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
Example of correct stubbing:
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
```

I tried different ways like `lenient mode`

```
lenient().doAnswer(params -> params.getArgument(0)).when(myInstance).myMethod(any());
```

Also I tried BDDMockito style:

```
given(myInstance.myMethod(any(UsedClass.class))).willReturn(usedClassResponse);
```

None of them worked.

Any idea please ?

Comment: I am having the same problem. It looks like Spring is re-wrapping the Mocked object and then Mockito no longer sees it as a Mock. Example: FooClass$MockitoMock$1815440712$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d55c43f9